# JavaFX – exclude/include parent and all its children from layout dynamically

Tags: layout, parent, javafx

**Background/Context:**

I have a HBox as a parent and many child Nodes (Buttons, TextFields, Labels…). The HBox is a child of other container (BorderPane/VBox/Grid)

**My questions:**

How do I dynamically remove/exclude the parent (HBox) and all its children from layout?

I am looking for some three-state property on Node (like in Microsoft WPF):

*Visible* – visible and participate in layout

*Collapsed* – is not visible and do not participate in layout (applies to its children as well)

*Hidden* – is not visible but participate in layout

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms590101.aspx

What options does JavaFX offer?

**My solutions so far:**

```
hBox.setManaged(false);
```

- this work only for HBox, its children are still present

root.getChildren().remove(hBoxTop);

root.getChildren().add(hBoxTop);

- Well, this looks like it could work.., but for example in case of root being BorderPane, once I remove/add and remove the HBox, the space after it remains unused. I already tried requestLayout() but id does not force thr rrot to fill it. Am I missing something? Is it correct approach to this problem?

**Edited:**

Well, I got this working.

Dynamically removing and adding for this specific case can be achieved by:

*Remove:*

```
root.setTop(null);
```

*Add:*

```
root.setTop(hBoxTop);
```

When I did not call setTop(null) on removal, BorderPane still reserved space for HBox (even after removal from its children).

IMHO: it is not very good model as it is parent-container specific. For example if I change, BorderPane to VBox a I had to change these methods as well. For VBox, remove/add on children collection works but I need to remember index so that HBox appears at same place after calling add.

Answer (score 1):

Using `root.setTop(null)` is not a good idea because as you say it's specific to BorderPane.

I think the best solution is to use:

```
root.getChildren().remove(yourPane);
```

And use layout methods to place your other childrens as you want.
But maybe you should not use a BorderPane in the first place with the behaviors you want in your application.

Notice you can also do `root.getChildren().clear()` to remove all component and add it again to your layout but differently.

Answer (score 1):

Many years later, been facing the same issue but managed to work it out after a good research.
So am having a VBox which whose components am updating if a certain condition is filled by the user. setting visible and managed to false completely removes the Nodes from view and setting these back to true shows the Nodes back dynamically.

```
if (!comboBox.getItems().isEmpty()) {
   vBox.setVisible(true);
   vBox.setManaged(true);
} else {
   vBox.setVisible(false);
   vBox.setManaged(false);
}
```

The above should work fine.